# Jcrop plugin with a other JS function in same context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcrop

I'm having trouble with the JCrop plugin.

I have this little code:

```
        $('#preview').attr('src', response).Jcrop();
        $('.box').center();
```

response is an string that contains the img path.

My #preview is inside a .box element, and dynamically updated by JCrop.

The problem is, after the Jcrop(), the .box isn't center (center() function center the element in window).

If, in javascript console on browser I put the $('.box').center(); and press enter, the element is centered, normally.

Why this problem?

Is very difficult to create a fiddler for this, because the complexity of the code to simulate an dynamically image insert.

Thanks for the support already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#preview').attr('src', response).Jcrop({}, function() {
    $('.box').center();
});
```

Comment: Tks for the answer man. Works fine here. =], really tks. Up and Right answer.